# Can't reference data objects in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't wrap my head around manipulating the data object in d3js. I'm planning to create a chart composed of horizontal bars to hold data elements. Each data element is a circle. I figured out how to insert circles into the different bars, but I'm stuck on how to equally space the circles in each bar. For example, if the width is 800 and there are 8 circles, the x attribute should be `100*i`.

Here's a link to my project: https://plnkr.co/edit/fHrdJsItEqA5qc35iUxG?p=preview

I think the problem is how to reference the data object in this block of code. Anyways, I would like to equally space the circles using `scaleBand` which I defined as variable `x` earlier in my code:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0,width]);
```

I think the solution would look something like this: `.attr("x",x.domain(data.map(function(d,i){return d[i]})); x.bandwidth()`, but obviously data is not the right object.

Selecting each bar and inserting circles:

```
  bar.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d,i){console.log(data_group[i].values.length);return data_group[i].values})
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class","circle")
.attr("width", width)
//.attr("x",) //how to equally space these circle elements???
.attr("height",20)
.attr("y", y.bandwidth())
console.log(y.bandwidth());
```

As always, I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code that are preventing it from working, including:

1. You aren't setting a domain for your `x` scale.
2. You are attempting to place `<circle>`s inside of `<rect>`s but you cannot nest shapes in SVGs. You should place both inside of a `<g>`.
3. A `<circle>`'s position is set using the `cx` and `cy` attributes (and you also need to provide it an `r` radius attribute).

To address your question, you will need to determine how you want your items laid out. Because you are referencing the index in your question, I will use that.

You are breaking your data into nested groups where each one has a `values` array. You are rendering a `<circle>` for each datum in that array, so you will want to determine the length of the longest `values` array.

```
var longest = data_group.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  return curr.values.length > acc ? curr.values.length : acc;
}, -Infinity);
```

Once you have the length of the longest `values` array, you can set the domain for your x scale.

You are using `d3.scaleBand` (`d3.scalePoint` would probably work better here), which is an ordinal scale. Ordinal scales work on discrete domains, which means that you will need to have a domain value for each possible input (the indices). For this, you will need to generate an array of the possible indices from `0` to `longest-1`.

```
var domainValues = d3.range(longest);
```

Now that you have the input domain values, you can set them for the `x` scale.

```
x.domain(domainValues);
```

Then, for each `<circle>`, you will set its `cx` value using the index of the circle in its group and the `x` scale.

```
.attr('cx', function(d,i) { return x(i); })
```

As I mentioned in the beginning, there are other errors in your code, so just fixing this won't get it running correctly, but it should push you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, quick question:  if the longest array was `8` and the width was `800`, would circles in smaller arrays also be spaced by the same amount (100) or would the x attributes adjust to fill up the width of the container?

Comment: Also, since it's not possible to nest shapes in SVGs, would the rectangle shape be unnecessary if all I want is to organize circles by rows?

Comment: You don't need the for loop: `var domainValues = d3.range(longest.length);`.

Comment: All of the rows would have the same spacing. You would need to create multiple scales if you wanted different spacing based on the number of values. If you are just grouping the circles, use a `<g>` (one per item in your `data_group` array).

Comment: I ignored `d3.range` because it was simple enough to create a range manually, but since it is a d3 example, I suppose I might as well use it.